# Why publishing persistent messages with RabbitMQ is so slow?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

While publishing messages with delivery_mode=1 (to a durable queue), RabbitMQ management panel shows around 2500 messages per second, but unfortunately when I try to publish same messages with delivery_mode=2 to make them persistent, incoming message rate drops to 15-20 messages per second. (using Python 2.7 and pika library)

Each message consists of a URL, so their sizes are small too... Also I'm publishing by using basic_publish().

Node stats on management panel shows the following data;

File descriptors: 55 / 1024 available

Socket descriptors: 1 / 829 available

Erlang processes: 248 / 1048576 available

Memory: 277MB / 12GB high watermark

Disk space: 1.6TB / 48MB low watermark

Also I/O statistics (I/O average time per operation) shows as following;
Read: 3.0ms

Write: 0.13ms

Seek: 0.05 ms

Sync: 70ms

Is this the normal behaviour of persistent queues on RabbitMQ or am I doing something wrong or can I do something for tuning performance?

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: Persistent queues are always slower as they involve a write to disk (to preserve messages in case of power loss), however, those figures are incredibly low. We manage to push 10k/s to a persistent queue without stressing it. Admittedly, we're using a higher spec server, but you don't seem to be stressing yours much. What's your CPU and Disk I/O like? Do you perhaps have slow (spinning platter) disks? ([htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) and [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) can help here)

Comment: @Basic I have a desktop grade Intel i7 server with 32GB memory and the disks are SATA disks. CPU load is very low, between 1.50-2.00 (for 8 cores), also producer is running on the same server, reading data from MongoDB, makes some sorting before sending to RabbitMQ etc. but doesnt write anything to disk, just reads.. Also memory has free space more than 20GB.

iotop shows around 80K/s "total disk write" and around 250K/s "actual disk write"

Comment: That's about 25% of the write speed for an average 5400 rpm HDD, but may be impacted by seeking for other processes. What's your disk wait%? We have our queue backed by SSDs. In addition, we try to make sure our raid setup is such that each major process gets a set of spindles/drives of its own, to avoid contention. I'm not sure how much of a difference that makes, but I'd remove MongoDB from the equation and re-test... Write a simple python script that pushes messages (random?) in a tight loop. Make sure you reuse the connection. Monitor speed with everything else down to localise bottleneck.

Comment: @Basic I just stopped the Mongodb, wrote a simple loop which publishes numbers from 0 to 50000, and if durable=true for queue_declare(), results are the same. When i set durable to false with queue_declare() it becomes fast. (Also all publishes using the same connection)

Here you can see my "iostat -x 2 5" results: http://pastebin.com/a0ds7vKx

Comment: @Basic In addition, for testing I used a crawler on same server and it's crawling more than 200 pages/sec and writing them to MongoDB without any performance problem.

Comment: @shehatesme how many subscribers do you have in this case?

Comment: @cantSleepNow just one, there is no load on server or RabbitMQ

Comment: @shehatesme usually when publishing rate drop you should increase the number of subscribers, so that the queues don't go into flow state

Comment: @cantSleepNow the rate is too low from the start, when the queue is empty too...

Comment: @shehatesme ah ok, than it's not the flow thing...

Comment: @cantSleepNow its really weird... everything seems normal